# How to make a custom route in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to do something like this.

`MyUrl.com/ComicBooks/{NameOfAComicBook}`

I messed around with RouteConfig.cs but I'm completely new at this, so I'm having trouble.  `NameOfAComicBook` is a mandatory parameter.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();


        routes.MapRoute("ComicBookRoute",
                            "{controller}/ComicBooks/{PermaLinkName}",
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "ShowComicBook" }
                            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult ShowComicBook(string PermaLinkName)
{


    // i have a breakpoint here that I can't hit


    return View();
}
```

Comment: Is `NameOfAComicBook` an optional or mandatory parameter? Include more details.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I updated my question.  (mandatory)

Comment: Show your routes, including what you tried and explain what is not working.

Comment: Can you post your current `RouteConfig.cs` file?

Comment: If you have `UrlParameter.Optional` on `NameOfAComicBook`, remove it to make it required one. But I still want to see your efforts to set `RouteConfig`.

Comment: Specific routes need to be before the `Default` route - and it would need to be `"ComicBooks/{PermaLinkName}"` (no `{controller}`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Noticed that attribute routing is also enabled.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

you can also set up the route directly in the controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("ComicBooks")]
public class ComicBooksController : Controller {    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{PermaLinkName}")] //Matches GET ComicBooks/Spiderman
    public ActionResult ShowComicBook(string PermaLinkName){
        //...get comic book based on name
        return View(); //eventually include model with view
    }
}
```

Comment: My ComicBookRoute has Controller="Home" so I was expecting it to get processed by HomeController.